# How to use php array variables on html to output a ul list?

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays, web

```
        //Setting up variables
        $server = "**********";
        $username = "**********";
        $password = "******";
        $database = "*******";

        //Connecting to Server
        mysql_connect($server, $username, $password)or die (mysql_error());
        //echo "Connected to MySQL";

        //Connecting to database
        mysql_select_db($database) or die (mysql_error());
        //echo "Connected to my Database";

        //variable selecting the reach_codes table
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reach_Codes");


        //set variable to store column arrays
        $fault_Codes = array();
        //while loop fetching all rows
        while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
        {
            $fault_Codes[] = $row['fault_ID'];
        }

        echo $fault_Codes[1];



        mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Hi Everyone so I am relatively new to web programming, but I program in c++, so I wanted to make this website to display some fault code information since I work on forklifts at work just to make my life easier. I now how arrays work, I just can't find information on how to use those array variables on a  on html any help or pointing in the right direction will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: So I keep getting a parse error: syntax error on the same line I put the first <ul> tag maybe cuz I am a little bit tired I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why use array when u can easily echo a HTML code in php..

```
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo "<li>{$row}</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: thanks I try something like this but I probably messed up the sintax, all other answers seem appropriate too if I was using the array. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

just make sure your file ends with a .php extension and then you can do something like this. (Assuming your code above is in the same file )

```
<ul>
    <? foreach($fault_codes as $code) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $code;?></li>
    <? } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Two quick notes. First, I find it's more readable to use the [alternate syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) in this situation (i.e. `foreach(...):` and `endforeach;`. Second, since you're assuming short tags are enabled, you can just do `<?=$code?>` rather than using `echo` explicitly in that situation.

Comment: @AgentConundrum Well I guess it's a matter of opinion... the way I wrote is more readable for me, and also you can't use a 'mathching brackets' keyboard shortcut in a text editor without brackets can you? haha. I am very much aware of the `<?=$codde?>` style, but I was trying to emulate the OP's style using `echo`

Comment: I wasn't criticizing. I was just trying to add some supplemental information that you or OP might not know about. You're probably right about IDE support, but I don't have a problem with it since I wouldn't use those constructs anywhere but surrounding a raw-HTML block, and the `<?php?>` tags would be just as recognizable to the IDE in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is in a view file you can use this syntax:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($falt_codes as $item): ?>
    <li><?= $item ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

<strike>The `<?=` tag is shorthand for `<?php echo;` but you will need to have `short-open-tag` enabled in your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) (unless your running version 5.4.0 or greater).</strike>

**Edit** According to a comment on another answer, the short tag `<?=` has been depreciated and is in bad form.  I obviously didn't get that memo.

**Edit 2:**  The following is from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) regarding the afforementioned `<?=`:

> This directive [short-open-tag] also affected the shorthand `<?=` before PHP 5.4.0, which is identical to `<? echo`. Use of this shortcut required short_open_tag to be on. Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.

Seeing as how they have made this a first class citizen I'm at a loss as to why it was regarded it as depreciated in the comment.

Comment: I think the point wasn't that `<?=` was discouraged so much as it was that short tags were discouraged. (I don't really know why it's discouraged, though I do remember reading something back in the day that said it clashed with XML or something.) When 5.4 comes out, it will detach the nice `<?=` behaviour from the short tags syntax, so that you can have short tags disabled but still use it, thus sidestepping the issue. Also remember that 5.4 isn't out yet, so there isn't a production version out right now that doesn't require short tags for this to work, which is why it's still discouraged.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the very informative and educational comment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable shortcodes in the php.ini on the server for the aforementioned to work.

Comment: by shortcode tdk2fe is referring to <?= which means the same thing as <?php echo except that it is supposedly deprecated and considered bad form anymore.

Comment: @Kai: Psh.  Screw that.  I like short tags.  They can have my <?= when they pry it from my cold dead hands.

Comment: PHP isn't exactly known for it's elegance :)

Comment: @chao - lol yeah I know. I don't see why people get all up in arms over something like that when it's your site and your choice to run whatever version of PHP you choose. I on the other hand have to conform to certain expectations because I work for a client driven firm. Rules, you know.